# checkbox status in php

Tags: php, forms

I have a form with get method in php. In the form I created a checkbox which named Student.

I use these codes to show the details about the users in submit button action.

In the details page it shows error in it when the users aren't student. There is no problem when users are student :

```
if($_GET['student'] == "on")
{
    print "Student";
}
else
{
    print "Not student";
}
```

Comment: The code you provided has no errors.

Comment: @Tikkes it shows error in this line : if($_GET['student'] == "on")

Comment: @aliboy38 what's the error though?

Comment: The notice (not error) is that the index 'student' is not defined. See my answer.

Comment: In that case, @vusan's answer will surely help

Comment: You can avoid that issue in general by adding a hidden input field. Its way more convenient, plus many frameworks are doing it anyway for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also put new condition as:

```
if(isset($_GET['student'] && $_GET['student'] == "on")
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution is to add a hidden field which defaults to an empty value to omit the isset() call

```
<input type="hidden" name="student" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="student" value="on">
```

The reason you have to do this is because the browser does not send any value at all if the checkbox is not checked (not even an empty one, the key is just missing).